# Broken screen, monitor won’t connect

Tags: laptop, display, hdmi

I have a **Gigabyte Sabre 15** with a broken screen, I recently purchased a monitor (Philips LCD monitor) and am trying (and failing) to connect it. From what I can see, there is only one cable that connects the laptop and monitor (this is the HDMI cable I’m assuming) but it **won’t connect** for some reason...

I’m a complete newbie when it comes to monitors and laptops in general so I’m not sure if the monitor should turn on even if it isn’t connected. I’ve tried <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> (**and <kbd>F2</kbd> which has the LCD monitor symbol**) but to no avail.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Dumb questions first... Does the Philips monitor work? Is it plugged in to the wall?

Comment: I’ve tried to find a plug to put it in but nothing else seems to fit in. I’ve found one that should plug into the wall but it only has these three slots going inwards... not sure if that should be plugged into the monitor somehow.

Comment: Does it look something like this? https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71X3IxyGN9L._SY355_.jpg If so, this needs to be plugged into the monitor to give it power.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that but I can’t see anywhere to plug it into the monitor, at least not near all the other plugs. If it helps, here is what the plugs look like. https://s14.postimg.cc/ng9xu07kh/D63_ECE6_D-_D311-4972-87_BB-1196_C16_B081_C.jpg

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what kind of Philips monitor you have? Or post a picture of the connection ports on the back? Unless the picture you just posted was of your monitor.

Comment: The monitor is ‘Philips LCD monitor V-line 216V6’ (https://www.philips.com.au/c-p/216V6LHSB2_75/lcd-monitor) and yes, the picture was of my monitor.

Comment: Looking at your monitor from above, let's say that the HDMI cable you have plugged in is on the left side. On the right side, are there any connectors that look like they fit your power cable? Another question: did you buy this from the store, or from Craigslist or something? There are other kinds of power cables that look circular and whoever you bought it from might have given you the wrong one. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpmUj.jpg

Comment: the only ports for plugs are on the left side (see the picture above) and there isn’t anywhere for the wall to monitor plug to be inserted. There aren’t any other cables that can connect to my laptop (only the HDMI). I brought the monitor from officeworks (assuming you aren’t Australian - it’s an Australian tech/stationery/office shop) by the looks of the picture, that’s the cable that I actually need, at least according to the instruction manual, to plug in (wall to monitor)

Comment: Yep, now that I'm looking more closely it seems like your inputs are (from left to right): HDMI, VGA, audio, power. Gonna need a new power cable.

Comment: Yup, that’s what I was starting to suspect. Do you have a rough idea of what cable I’m looking for?

Comment: I found this user manual for a similar Philips model. Check out page 2, and look for the AC/DC adapter. Not sure how they work in Australia, but in America they come in two pieces, like the one on the left. Laptop power cables usually work the same way. 

http://download.p4c.philips.com/files/2/216v6lhsb2_01/216v6lhsb2_01_dfu_aen.pdf?locales=en_us,en_aa,en_au,en_ca,en_global,en_id,en_in,en_my,en_nz,en_ph,en_pk,en_sa,en_sg,en_za

Comment: Does your monitor look like the one in the manual? If so you'll probably want something like this. 

https://www.amazon.com/power-adapter-Philips-Magnavox-15MF605T/dp/B001UQBCGE

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you should definitely take first.

1. Make sure the monitor is plugged in and turns on. Using the [monitor cable](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71X3IxyGN9L._SY355_.jpg) you have, stick it in [this connector](http://www.microcenter.com/Content/Content%20Graphic/Images/130_HOW8003931A-12.jpg) on the back of your monitor and then plug the other end into the wall. Are there lights on the monitor that turn on? Can you see anything on the screen other than inky black darkness?
2. Plug in the monitor to your laptop (making sure it's on as well!) using the [HDMI cable](http://www.onda-tablet.com/media/wysiwyg/Onda_Tablet_HDMI_Cable_2.jpg), after verifying that the monitor works. See if anything happens to the external monitor - can you see your desktop background?
3. Assuming you have Windows, you can right click on the desktop of your new monitor, click on "Display Settings" or "Personalization," and from there change the external monitor settings to something like "Duplicate." You should be home free if you can get this far.

~

Failing any of these steps, we'll need to know...

A. Exactly what kind of Philips monitor do you have? Post pictures of the connections on the back.

B. How is the screen broken on your laptop? Does it turn on at all?